# Permission denied errors when creating app with custom OpenShift cartridge

Tags: openshift, selinux

I'm using OpenShift Origin and developing a cartridge for the first time. When my bin/install and bin/control scripts are running I've noticed "Permission denied" errors when they try to access anything in the cartridge usr dir. In the node platform.log I see the offending command that OpenShift runs looks like this (where my bin/control start tries to run a script in usr):

```
/sbin/runuser -s /bin/sh 5351e627ee5a934f290001d2 -c "exec /usr/bin/runcon 'unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c0,c1004' /bin/sh -c \"set -e; /var/lib/openshift/5351e627ee5a934f290001d2/mycart/bin/control start \""
```

Since the usr dir is a symlink I originally thought it was related to that, but now I think it's related to selinux (which I don't know much about). If I do a "ls -Z" on my app's cartridge dir the files are "system_u:object_r:openshift_var_lib_t:s0:c0,c1004" but the contents of the usr dir are "unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0", so it doesn't match what's in the above command.

I used the oo-admin-cartridge command to install the cartridge to my Origin VM.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was running "chcon -R -u system_u -t bin_t usr/" before installing the cartridge with oo-admin-cartridge. Built-in cartridges are not affected by this problem (checked nodejs), so I feel like it might be a oo-admin-cartridge bug. I would expect it to massage the selinux permissions instead of using whatever I provide.